# ORA-01034: ORACLE not available

Tags: oracle, docker, dockerfile

I am following this [reamde](https://github.com/oracle/docker-images/blob/master/OracleWebLogic/samples/12212-oradb-wlsstore/README.md) to create a Oracle database. I run the following command:

`docker run -it --network=SampleNET --rm store/oracle/database-instantclient:12.2.0.1 sqlplus sys/Oradoc_db1@InfraDB:1521/mindshift AS SYSDBA`

and get this message:

```
Enter user-name: weblogic
Enter password: 
ERROR:
ORA-01034: ORACLE not available
ORA-27101: shared memory realm does not exist
Linux-x86_64 Error: 2: No such file or directory
Additional information: 3701
Additional information: 1724833639
Process ID: 0
Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0
```

When I pulled the image and ran the scripts this was the output:

```
  domain_name     : [base_domain]
    admin_port      : [7001] 
    domain_path     : [/u01/oracle/user_projects/domains/base_domain]
    production_mode : [prod]
    admin password  : [welcome1]
    admin name      : [AdminServer]
    admin username  : [weblogic]
```

I am been trying to find a solution for a few days where I can have my own Oracle database locally using docker.

```
`[oracle@7d929b104a08 /]$  echo $ORACLE_SID`
`ORCLCDB`
` echo $ORACLE_HOME
`/u01/app/oracle/product/12.2.0/dbhome_1`

`[oracle@7d929b104a08 /]$ ps -ef | grep smon`
`oracle     146     1  0 17:53 ?        00:00:00 ora_smon_ORCLCDB`
`oracle     671   631  0 17:56 ?        00:00:00 grep --color=auto smon`
```

Answer (score 2):

Most probably the parameters `ORACLE_HOME` and `ORACLE_SID` have not been properly set.

```
$ echo $ORACLE_SID
....                    -->> Look what you get
$ echo $ORACLE_HOME
....                  
$ ps -ef | grep smon    -->> Look for smon background process which
ora_smon_InfraDB        --.. should include ORACLE_SID in it.

$ ORACLE_SID=InfraDB    -->> set to a valid value like these ones.
$ ORACLE_HOME=/u01/app/oracle/product/12.2.0.1/dbhome_1

$ lsnrctl status        -->> Look whether listener is ON
$ lsnrctl start         -->> If not, then start the listener.
```

Comment: I added my response to the question for better format reasons and it is relevant. Thank you for posting.

Answer (score 0):

```
ORA-01034: ORACLE not available
ORA-27101: shared memory realm does not exist
Linux-x86_64 Error: 2: No such file or directory
```

typical error when your instance is not startet. Check if your instance really startet. Does DB creation runs without error?

Comment: I did not see any error no. This is going at 12 hours today and I have yet been able to to simply have a local database with a SQL script that has create and insert statements in it.

Comment: your service_name is correct? can you post you creation command for database?